# Al cargar datos de una tabla recorriendo array meter una validacion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas e intentado hacer que cuando este pintando los datos de una tabla y se cumpla la condición en vez de pintar un dato me ponga una etiqueta o un label-success para que cuando este en verde o en otro color pueda acceder a el, ya lo e hecho con html y php pero ahora quiero hacerlo de diferente.
Me marca error en el if

Código

```
   for(var i=0; i<resp.length; i++)
    {
      console.log(resp[i]);

  html+= '<tr><td>'+resp[i].fecha_registro+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].dias_+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].contacto_nombre+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].modelo+
        '</td><td class="center"><span class="center' if(resp[i].servicio==0){'label-success'}else{'label-warning'}'"></span>'
    +resp[i].servicio+
        '</td><td>'+resp[i].ventas+
        '</td></tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error que veo está un la concatenación que intentas realizar en el **if**
Te recomiendo lo cambies a esta forma:

```
 var labelType = (resp[i].servicio == 0) ? 'label-success' : 'label-warning'; 
 html+= '<tr><td>'+resp[i].fecha_registro+
    '</td><td>'+resp[i].dias_+
    '</td><td>'+resp[i].contacto_nombre+
    '</td><td>'+resp[i].modelo+
    '</td><td class="center"><span class="label ' + labelType + '"></span>'
    +resp[i].servicio+
    '</td><td>'+resp[i].ventas+
    '</td></tr>';
```

Es más sencillo si usas el operador ternario, que básicamente es un if comprimido en una sola linea, y luego lo concatenas a tu texto como cualquier cadena.
Para más información del operador ternario checa [How do you use the ? : (conditional) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259982/how-do-you-use-the-conditional-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: gracias amigo me sirvió bastante, investigare un poco mas sobre los operadores ternarios